# oracle ssl setup not getting configured

Tags: oracle, ssl, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

Am trying to create the ssl below is my tnsnames.ora in server side,  found only one listener file in grid location:
Need to configure SSL on 2484 port on TMSU 1521 port, 2485 port on MISU port, and 2486 port on LGNU port, need confirmation is that i need to add the entry in grid/network listener.ora file with below

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = dztup)(PORT = 2484))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = dztup)(PORT = 2485))
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = dztup)(PORT = 2486))
```

Listener.ora below file found in grid/network/admin location:-

```
[oracle@DZTUPadmin]$ cat /u01/app/12.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
#Backup file is  /u01/app/12.2.0/grid/srvm/admin/listener.ora.bak.zdb-uat line added by Agent
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/12.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ENABLE_GLOBAL_DYNAMIC_ENDPOINT_LISTENER=ON              # line added by Agent
VALID_NODE_CHECKING_REGISTRATION_LISTENER=SUBNET                # line added by Agent
```

Below tnsnames.ora file found in ORACLE_HOME /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

msu =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = msu)
    )
  )

LISTENER_TSU =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))


msuAT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = msu)
    )
  )

LISTENER_LGNU =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))


LISTENER_msu =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))


TSUAT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TSU)
    )
  )

TSU =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TSU)
    )
  )

LGNU =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = LGNU)
    )
  )

LGNUAT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DZTUP)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = LGNU)
    )
  )
```

Any suggestions on this

Comment: any suggestions how to configure it

Comment: any guidelines or suggestion would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix this issue